# How to toggle item by id or index ? React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to opet child component by clicked item. FIrst check code:

```
    <div className="d-flex">
      {boardList.map((list) => (
        <div className="card m-3 p-3" key={list.id}>
          <div className="d-flex flex-column">
            <h6> {list.name} </h6>

            <ul className="list-group">
              {list.cards.map((card) => (
                <li className="list-group-item" key={card.id}>
                  {card.name}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul> 

            {isVisible ? (
              <TodoForm onCloseForm={onCloseForm} />
            ) : (
              <small 
                className="mt-2"
                onClick={showInput}
              > 
                Add new task + 
              </small>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
```

This is work but when I click on 'Add new task +' a child component opens up to me everywhere. i want only the component with the selected id or index to open.

also component for this :

```
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);
  const [boardList, setBoardList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axiosInstance
      .get("")
      .then((res) => {
        setBoardList(res.data);
        console.log("resp", boardList);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  const showInput = () => {
    setIsVisible(true);
  };

  const onCloseForm = () => {
    setIsVisible(false);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

All the items of the resultant array from `boardList.map` are depending on the same state `isVisible`, that's why when you click on one of them all the items mimic the same behaviour.

What you need is to create a component with its own state to encapsulate this part of your code

```
{isVisible ? (
  <TodoForm onCloseForm={onCloseForm} />
  ) : (
  <small 
    className="mt-2"
    onClick={showInput}
  > 
  Add new task + 
</small>
)}
```

This way every instance of this new component would have its own `isVisible` so they no longer would affect their siblings state.

The component would look like this.

```
const NewComponent = () => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  return <>
    {isVisible ? (
        <TodoForm onCloseForm={onCloseForm} />
    ) : (
      <small className="mt-2" onClick={() => setIsVisible(true)}>
        Add new task +
      </small>
    )}
  </>
};
```